# How to use color by number?

Tags: beamer, xetex, color

I'm trying to use Bettini's QSource Highlight IDE to colorize my python code. Generated LaTeX output is something like:

```
\noindent
\mbox{}\textcolor{#121b28}{a}\textcolor{#0000de}{=}\textcolor{#0da344}{10}
```

But I'm getting error:

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \iterate.
<to be read again>
1
l.72 }
You meant to type ## instead of #, right?
Or maybe a } was forgotten somewhere earlier, and things
are all screwed up? I'm going to assume that you meant ##.
```

Examples of `xcolor` and `color` package define colors by a different way. I'm looking for a way to be able to use a color by its hexadecimal RGB value ( generated code) in `xelatex` using `beamer`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify the color mode if you want to use it with `\textcolor`, and remove the `#`:

[image]

### Notes:

- I added an additional `{}` around the `=` to get the proper math spacing.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\textcolor[HTML]{121b28}{a} \textcolor[HTML]{0000de}{{}={}} \textcolor[HTML]{0da344}{10}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I'm going to report this bug to QSource Highlight IDE.